# chmod from user to group recursive

Tags: command-line, chmod

I have a folder ( Android-SDK ) with a lot of executables ( user only ) in it - now I want to share this between 2 users ( jenkins + login-user ) - now I have to set executable flags for every executable for group - one option would be

```
chmod g+x -R android-sdk
```

but this has a lot of collateral damage ( +x on non-executables ) - is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution to set all (r, w and x) group permissions equally to the owner permissions, you can use the simple command:

```
chmod g=u -R android-sdk
```

Example:

- File before: `rwx r-- r--`
- File afterwards: `rwx rwx r--`

Comment: If the permissions are tight, giving away write permissions might not be what OP wants. +1 for the simplicity, though.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` to find executable files and apply `chmod` on them.

To list files executable by the owner:

```
find . -type f -perm /u+x
```

To apply `chmod` on them:

```
find . -type f -perm /u+x -exec chmod g+x {} +
```

Comment: I would vote if I had any left for today... Will try to remember it tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! upvoted - just accepted @ByteCommander 's answer because it was simpler and kind of what I had in mind and searched for when answering

Comment: Here's the promised upvote.